# Implementing Listening data changes for Android Loaders

Tags: android, loader

I wrote simple `Loader` as below code and i want expect to add data to `List` and my RecyclerView adapter know that by refreshing list with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

My loader class:

```
public class StringLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<RobotViewModel>> {
    private        List<RobotViewModel> cache;
    private static List<RobotViewModel> model;

    public StringLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (cache == null) {
            forceLoad();
        } else {
            super.deliverResult(cache);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<RobotViewModel> loadInBackground() {
        Log.e("LOAD......... ", "new");
        model = new ArrayList<>();
        return model;
    }

    public void addCommand() {
        RobotViewModel temp = new RobotViewModel();
        temp.setMessage("hello");
        temp.setMessageType(SV.RobotMessageType.SENT_BY_ROBOT.ordinal());
        model.add(temp);

        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
        cache = data;
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }
}
```

i use `addCommand()` method from activity:

```
public void clickOnSendCommand() {
    loader.addCommand();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

my activity and implementing adapter and Loader:

```
public class ActivityRegister extends BaseActivities {

    private RobotMessagesAdapter adapter;
    private StringLoader         loader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        ActivityRegisterPresenter presenter = new ActivityRegisterPresenter(this);
        ActivityRegisterViewModel viewModel = new ActivityRegisterViewModel();
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setPresenter(presenter);

        List<RobotViewModel> model = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RobotMessagesAdapter(this, model);
        binding.registerRobot.setAdapter(adapter);

        loader = (StringLoader) getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.string_loader_id, null, loaderCallbacks);
    }

    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<RobotViewModel>> loaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<RobotViewModel>>() {
        @Override
        public Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new StringLoader(getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> loader, List<RobotViewModel> data) {
            adapter.setData(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<RobotViewModel>> loader) {
            adapter.setData(Collections.<RobotViewModel>emptyList());
        }
    };
```

`setData()` method on adapter:

```
public void setData(List<RobotViewModel> data) {
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

adding items to list normally don't have any problem, and work fine, but i want to add item to that and refresh adapter

Comment: @pskink i dont understand me

Comment: @pskink in this source code `mObserver`  can be register by `cursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);` i dont have Cursor and my `AsyncTaskLoader` is an `List<RobotViewModel>` not `Cursor`, how can i use `registerContentObserver`?

Comment: @pskink i'm trying to load data from database on background and cache data on device orientation

Comment: @pskink ok, so could you link me how can i cache data on change orientation device? i can't find this feature

Comment: have you used `saveInstancestate()` method to store data on origination change.

Comment: have you used `saveInstancestate()` method to store data on origination change.

Comment: What kind of error you get? Please share error log cat. Else please explain that when you update you `Collection` that what happen ?

Comment: @Shailesh i don't get any error, but i cant renew `model` on `StringLoader` class and update recyclerview

Comment: When you add new data then check your data length. It will changed or not then after you notify adapter to new item is added and refresh adapter

Comment: @Shailesh problem is your note, after adding item that cause of changing list size and i have only one item

Answer (score 0):

For custom loader you have to create your own observer, you will keep observing the URI of table whenever there is a change in table then, you will get callback on your observer or loader and you can update your view.

You can use some other object other than cursor to point to the loaded data (like list etc). In this we won't be having privilege to notify ContentResolver through cursor. The application may also not have a content Provider, to track URI changes. In this scenario we use BroadcastReceiver or explicit ContentObserver to achieve automatic view updation. This is as follows:

We need to define our custom loader which extends AsyncTaskLoader and implements all its abstract methods. Unlike CursorLoader, our Custom Loader may or may not use a content Provider and it's constructor may not call to ContentResolver.query(), when this loader is instatiated. So we use a broadcast receiver to serve the purpose.
We need to instantiate a BroadCastReceiver or ContentObserver in OnStartLoading() method of abstract AsyncTaskLoader class.
This BroadCast receiver should be defined to receive data-changing broadcasts from content provider or any system events(Like new app installed) and it has to call loader's onContentChanged() method, to notify the loader about the data change. Loader automatically does the rest to load the updated data and call onLoadFinished() to update the view.

For more details refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html

**Sample Code**

Add this code in your activity

```
private final ContentObserver mObserver = new ThrottledContentObserver( 
new ThrottledContentObserver.Callbacks() {
                 @Override
               public void onThrottledContentObserverFired() {
                    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
               }
            });
```

and register the below variable  on **onResume()** by using
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);

and unregister it on **onPause()** by using `getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);`

Comment: could you update my code? if very difficult for me to understand it

Comment: please let me to check that